# Display value through pointer of function

Tags: c

Good morning.

I'm trying to affect a value (in different type) in a void* by using pointer functions.
It will allow me the create a table of value without specify the type (it's a homework for next week).
But I have some error in my code and and don't know how I can display my values (because they are in tab of void with size).
Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef void * (* t_data_default_init)();
typedef void (* t_data_reset_to_init)(void * p_data);
typedef void (* t_data_cpy)(void *p_data_dst, void *p_data_src);

typedef struct struct_vector{
    size_t nbElement;
    void* element;
    t_data_default_init data_default_init;
    t_data_reset_to_init data_reset_to_init;
    t_data_cpy data_cpy;
    size_t size_of_data;
}s_vector;

typedef s_vector* p_s_vector;

void my_struct_default_init(p_s_vector p_vector){
    p_vector->nbElement = 0;
    p_vector->element = NULL;
}

void my_struct_reset_to_default(p_s_vector p_vector){
    p_vector->nbElement = 0;
    if(p_vector->element != NULL){
        free(p_vector->element);
        p_vector->element = NULL;
    }
}

void my_struct_copy(p_s_vector p_dest, p_s_vector p_src){
    p_dest->nbElement = p_src->nbElement;
    p_dest->element = malloc(sizeof(p_src->size_of_data) * (p_src->nbElement + 1));
    strcpy(p_dest->element, p_src->element);
}

p_s_vector vector_alloc(size_t n, size_t size_of_data, t_data_default_init data_default_init
    , t_data_reset_to_init data_reset_to_init, t_data_cpy data_cpy){
    
    p_s_vector vect = malloc(sizeof(s_vector));
    vect->size_of_data = size_of_data;
    vect->data_default_init = data_default_init;
    vect->data_reset_to_init = data_reset_to_init;
    vect->data_cpy = data_cpy;
    vect->nbElement = n;
    vect->element = malloc(n * vect->size_of_data);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
         vect->data_default_init(vect->element + (i * vect->size_of_data));
         //vect->element[i] = data_default_init(vect->size_of_data);
    }
    
    // p_s_vector vect = malloc(sizeof(s_vector));
    // vect->nbElement = n;
    // vect->element = malloc(sizeof(double) * n);
    // for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        // vect->element[i] = i; 
    // }
    return vect;
}

void vector_free(p_s_vector p_vector){
    for(int i=0; i<p_vector->nbElement; i++){
        p_vector->data_reset_to_init(p_vector->element + i*p_vector->size_of_data);
        //p_vector->element[i] = data_reset_to_init(p_vector->size_of_data);
    }
    free(p_vector->element);
    p_vector->element = NULL;
    free(p_vector);
    p_vector = NULL;
}

void vector_insert(p_s_vector p_vector, size_t i, void * v){
    if(i < 0 || i > p_vector->nbElement)
        exit(0);
    else{   
        p_vector->nbElement++;
        
        void * temp = (void*) malloc(p_vector->size_of_data * (p_vector->nbElement));
        
        for(int k=0; k<i; k++){
            p_vector->data_cpy(temp + k * (p_vector->size_of_data), p_vector->element +k*(p_vector->size_of_data));
            p_vector->data_reset_to_init(p_vector->element +k*(p_vector->size_of_data));
        }
            
        p_vector->data_cpy(temp + i * (p_vector->size_of_data), v); 
        
        for(int k=i; k<p_vector->nbElement; k++){
            p_vector->data_cpy(temp + (k+1) * (p_vector->size_of_data), p_vector->element +k*(p_vector->size_of_data));
            p_vector->data_reset_to_init(p_vector->element +k*(p_vector->size_of_data));
        }
        
        free(p_vector->element);
        p_vector->element = temp;
    }
}

int main(){
    size_t n = 4;
    p_s_vector tab = vector_alloc(n,sizeof(char), my_struct_default_init, my_struct_reset_to_default, my_struct_copy);
    
    vector_insert(tab, 2, 'c');
    
    for(int i = 0; i<tab->nbElement; i++)
        printf("%c\n",tab->element+i*tab->size_of_data);
    
    
    vector_free(tab);
    return 0;
}
```

It's possible to use pointer function to display every types of value (int char etc...) through printf?
Thank you for your help

Comment: The first error I get is `error: pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic`. You must cast to a pointer to a type with a size (like `char*`) to be able to do arithmetic

Comment: If you are using `gcc`, I suggest adding these options when compiling: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -fanalyzer -g -fsanitize=address,undefined` - they will give you help to find the problems when compiling and also check that the program behaves properly in runtime